# Loop through a nested tables to get textbox values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using ASP.NET and C# to make a basic Sudoku game. As per my requirements, I have to implement the entire structure in the code-behind page.

I have 4 nested *for* loops that create the structure (table with 9 nested tables). In each inner cell, I then place a textbox control (81 total).

When playing the game, the user has the option to check their progress at any point in the game. I need a way to loop through every textbox control and store that value in an array so that I can check it against another 9x9 array that holds the solution to the puzzle.

How can I loop over the textboxes and store them logically. I would prefer to store then as another 9x9 array. That would make life very simple going forward.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Here's my code. I'm not sure how helpful it might be.

```
public partial class Sudoku : System.Web.UI.Page
{
//create objects to hold our puzzle pieces
private Puzzle puzzle;
private Box box;
private SudokuTextBox textbox;
private Number number;

//create an array to hold the solution
int[,] solution;
//and one to hold the user's answers
int[,] userAnswer;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //instantiate all of our objects
    //most of them are placeholders for the loops
    puzzle  = new Puzzle();
    box     = new Box();
    textbox = new SudokuTextBox();
    number  = new Number();

    // CHOOSING A SOLUTION

    //create a new random number generator
    Random random = new Random();

    //set the solution array number to a random number from 0-10
    //(11 because the maxValue is exclusive)
    solution = chooseSolution(random.Next(1, 11));

    // CREATING THE PUZZLE

    Table structure = new Table();      //table to be the outer structure of the puzzle
    TableRow row;                       //row variable to make new rows
    TableCell cell;                     //cell variable to make new cells
    Table boxTable;                     //table that will hold individual Boxes
    TableRow boxRow;                    //row that will hold 3 SudokuTextBoxes
    TableCell boxCell;                  //cell that will hold a single SudokuTextBoxes
    TextBox input;                      //textbox that will hold the textbox in SudokuTextBox
    int answer;                         //int to hold the answer to a particular textbox

    //start looping through the puzzle rows
    for (int pr = 0; pr < 3; pr++)
    {
        row = new TableRow();           //create a new outer row

        //another loop for puzzle columns
        for(int pc = 0; pc < 3; pc++)
        {
            cell = new TableCell();         //create a new outer cell
            boxTable = new Table();         //create a new inner table
            box = puzzle.getItem(pr, pc);   //find the box at the current location in the puzzle

            //another loop for box rows
            for (int br = 0; br < 3; br++)
            {
                boxRow = new TableRow();    //create a new inner row

                //another loop for box columns
                for(int bc = 0; bc < 3; bc++)
                {
                    boxCell = new TableCell();                      //create a new inner cell
                    textbox = box.getItem(br, bc);                  //find the SudokuTextBox at the current location in the box
                    //grab the answer to this particular SudokuTextBox from the solutions array
                    answer = solution[ (pr + br + (2 * pr)), (pc + pr + (2 * pc)) ];
                    number.setNumber(answer);                       //set the Number to the found answer
                    textbox.setTextBoxValue(number);                //fill in the textbox with Number
                    input = textbox.getTextBox();                   //grab the textbox inside SudokuTextBox and store it
                    input.MaxLength = 1;                            //only allow 1 character to be typed into the textbox
                    boxCell.Controls.Add(input);                    //add the textbox to the inner cell
                    boxRow.Controls.Add(boxCell);                   //add the inner cell to the inner row
                } //end box column loop

                boxTable.Controls.Add(boxRow);  //add the inner row to the inner table

            } //end box row loop
            cell.Controls.Add(boxTable);        //add the inner table to the outer cell
            row.Controls.Add(cell);             //add the outer cell to the outer row
        } //end puzzle column loop
        structure.Controls.Add(row);            //add the outer row to the outer table
    } //end puzzle row loop

    pnlPuzzle.Controls.Add(structure);          //add the outer table to the panel on the page
}
```

Comment: post relevant code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that code has been posted it's clear that without a unique ID for each textbox you won't be able to re-assemble the array.

The TextBox class should provide a way to set an id - I think the property you want is ID - so I think your logic should be changed to this:

```
input = textbox.getTextBox();                   //grab the textbox inside SudokuTextBox and store it
input.MaxLength = 1;       
// Define an ID that encodes the row and column
input.ID = string.Format("txtSudukoPuzzle_{0}_{1}", br, bc)
```

but I haven't worked with ASP.Net controls for a long time so don't quote me.  Once you got IDs against the controls it should be simple to re-assemble the results into an array again by parsing the row and column from the ID, possible using the logic posted by @poke

Comment: I hadn't thought about adding an ID to the textbox dynamically. That solved the problem, though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can just store them as a multidimensional array as well.

However, since you are on the code-behind and the text box components are probably not going to be generated by code but are rather layed out by hand (on the aspx site), you will have to place them manually into an array. Something like this:

```
TextBox[][] = new TextBox[][] {
    new TextBox[] { textBox1_1, textBox1_2, textBox1_3, …, textBox1_9 },
    new TextBox[] { textBox2_1, textBox2_2, textBox2_3, …, textBox2_9 },
    …
    new TextBox[] { textBox9_1, textBox9_2, textBox9_3, …, textBox9_9 },
};
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question as the question states "...I have 4 nested for loops that create the structure..." so I think they're asking how to iterate the values once the user has posted a change.

Comment: But OP seems comfortable looping over this structure, hence them asking whether it’s possible to store them like that too: *“How can I loop over the textboxes and store them logically. I would prefer to store them as another 9x9 array.”*

Comment: fair comment, and this seems like another in the growing list of questions that will be posted and never returned to.

Comment: Heh, that sounds likely. Anyway, my answer is just a good guess due to lack of information from the question. We’ll see how it goes, or maybe not ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use the mentioned method, because my textboxes are not given IDs. As i mentioned in the original post, all my code is generated in the code-behind. Therefore, they are not being implemented by hand. My biggest concern here is how to iterate over each one.